# Elementary functions are measurable, alternate limit proof

Tags: limits, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(E,\cal{E})$ be a measurable space, and let $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an elementary function, i.e. $f=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i\, I_{A_i}$ where
for each $i\geq 1$, $ \,I_{A_i}$ is the indicator function of $A_i$, the $A_i$ are disjoint, and $A_i \in \cal{E}$ for each $i$.

One way to prove this is discussed here: [Elementary functions are measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705725/elementary-functions-are-measurable#)

My question:
could this be proved as a limit of simple functions?

i.e., let $f_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i I_{A_i}$. We know that each $f_n$ is simple, and thus measurable on $\cal{E}$. And we know the limit of measurable functions is measurable.

I feel like i'm missing something. Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Yes, correct.__

Comment: Correct, but needed for that is a proof that limits of measurable functions are again measurable. And this without using that elementary functions are measurable (to avoid circularity). That might not be such a good idea. Also have a second look at the linked question. A more simple proof is provided in the meanwhile.